# Fixed point property for simple undirected graphs

Tags: graph-theory

We say that a simple, undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ has the *fixed point property (FPP)* if for every graph homomorphism $f:G\to G$ there is a vertex $v\in V$ such that $f(v) = v$.

If $G$ has the FPP, does $G\times G$ have the FPP (where by $\times$ we denote the [categorical product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_graphs) of graphs)?

Comment: In a homomorphism do you allow two neighbors to be mapped to the same vertex?

Comment: Btw you could ask whether when $G,H$ have FPP then so does $G\times H$.

Comment: That's right, but that question is maybe even more difficult? But I might change the question, yours looks actually more natural because it is more general. It is the better question in fact.

Comment: The version with $G\times H$ is listed as an open question in "The Fixed Vertex Property for Graphs" by Schröder: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11083-014-9337-5.

Comment: It's more difficult if you expect a positive answer, but easier if you expect a counterexample.

Comment: @YCor sorry I missed that question. Graph homomorphisms are usually defined to take edges to edges, so neighbours can't be mapped to the same vertex, see also https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_homomorphism